# Do I ever need to re-create listening socket?

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, network-programming, winsock2

Suppose I've created a socket, started `listen()`ing on it and run `accept()` in a loop to process incoming connections. I.e. smth like this:

```
s = socket();
bind(s, ...);
listen(s, ...);
loop {
    new_s = accept(s, ...);
    ...                               // do smth with new_s
}
```

For various reasons `accept()` can return an error and most of these errors say `this particular connection attempt failed, please carry on`. Is there any scenario when you have to close the socket and start from scratch (i.e. make new socket + bind + listen) in order to be (eventually) reachable by clients? What error (returned from `accept()`) tell me that? I.e. should I ever structure my logic like this:

```
loop {
    loop {
        s = socket();
        bind(s, ...);
        listen(s, ...);
        if !error { break; }
        sleep(1second);               // avoid busy loop
    }

    loop {
        new_s = accept(s, ...);
        if error {
            if error == ??? break;     <--- which error code(s)?
            continue;
        }
        ...                           // do smth with new_s
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

Specifically I am looking at `ENETDOWN` (Linux) and `WSAENETDOWN` (Winsock2) -- looks like these happen when someone restarts the network (interface). Will my previously created socket continue accepting connections once network is up? I doubt it, but even if it is the case -- how to properly avoid busy `accept` loop?

Other platforms may have other error codes -- how to write a code that will work on all of them?

Comment: I don't have an absolute answer (Windows in particular) but... I've never seen an issue on Linux: there is no "hard linkage" between the interface and the listening socket (even if you bound the socket to an interface-specific address instead of 0.0.0.0/ANY). So if the interface goes down and comes back up, I'm pretty sure everything will keep working fine. Aside from programming errors (EBADF, ENOTSOCK, EFAULT, etc.), I wouldn't expect any error from `accept` that you wouldn't handle by just retrying.

Comment: FWIW, tried this on my (linux) box: created a socket, bound it to a particular interface's address. Took that interface down. Nothing happened (program just continued waiting in `accept`). Brought the interface back up. Connected to the address from another system. Accept completed without complaint.

Comment: @GilHamilton Interesting... I wonder, in which circumstances `ENETDOWN` is returned from `accept()`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to recreate the listening socket if accept() fails on that listener (at least on Windows).

If one called bind on 0.0.0.0:(some port) - then you almost never need to worry about recreating the listening socket.

If one called bind on a specific IP address, and that IP address goes away, then you definitely need to recreate the listening socket (you aren't listening to anything anymore).

Comment: Well, which `accept` error codes should I treat as "time to re-create"?

Comment: "You don't need to recreate the listening socket if accept fails".

You only need to recreate the listening socket if it's bound to a specific IP address and that IP address goes away.

Comment: if "IP address goes away" -- will `accept` fail with an error? if yes -- which one?